# Is my pediatrician missing something about my 3 month old's gas pain?

Tags: infant, sleep, gas

My 3 month old has cried out at between 4:00 and 6:00 a.m. for hours in gas pain almost every night for the past 6 weeks or so.  There have been 2 or 3 nights in this time where she did not have an issue.  She usually nurses right before bedtime around 6:45 p.m., between 12 and 2 a.m. (depending on how she sleeps), and then again sometime during the gassy episodes at around 5 a.m.  The nights when she has not had pain have usually happened because she had an unusually good first stretch of sleep and did not nurse until after 3:30 a.m.  I know it is gas pain because she is scrunching her legs up and crying very shrilly.  Unfortunately feeding her at 5 does not usually help to release gas or a bowel movement.  It does sometimes put her in a deep enough sleep that she doesn't notice the pain.  To help soothe her I usually give her a pacifier to suck on and put a gently warmed rice sock on her tummy.  I'm loathe to try more invasive things because she's usually half asleep crying.  However my spouse and I are getting exhausted from the 4 a.m. morning and I can't imagine baby is getting good quality sleep either!

I've talked to either a nurse or doctor at my pediatrician's several times describing the fact that the episodes can last up to 2 hours, basically until Baby's usual wake-up and feeding (when she often does release gas and a bowel movement because she's finally wide awake - during the day she rarely has gassy episodes and usually about 3 dirty diapers, all loose to very loose).  All I ever get is "that's normal for her age."  One nurse did advise the rice sock, and it does seem to help her feel better.

I've seen online all the suggestions for Mom to avoid dairy or "gassy" foods, but I'm loathe to complicate life with an infant further without real medical cause and I don't know of any doctor who routinely advises a breastfeeding mother to avoid certain foods unless an allergy really is suspected.  My baby doesn't spit up much that we can see but does seem to occasionally spit up and then swallow it back down.  She's pretty cheerful, though, so I don't suspect reflux.  It's just this night time episode when she's been lying still for hours after a feeding, hits light sleep, and then notices the pain.

I've heard that 4 months is the magic time when the usual gas pain will go away.  I've been planning on gritting my teeth about this whole issue until my baby's 4 month check-up and bringing it up yet again if it's still happening.  What should I say when I do, or should I try calling in yet again with other information?  Could the pediatrician be missing something?

Comment: I'd like to add a link that backs up the accepted answer to this question on [actual studies supporting an elimination diet for breastfeeding mothers](http://scienceofmom.com/2012/07/03/tummy-troubles-colic-and-mamas-diet/). So helpful to see the evidence out there.

Comment: Why do I get the same then and men bottle fed? I had this x10 turned out he was intolerant to my milk. Though not fully gone I was only having 1 hr sleep now he cried at times like yours. I wondered if he was teething my self

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually quite common for foods that a breastfeeding mother is eating to cause gas or colicy behavior in a child. A friend had to avoid eating chocolate because her child would cry on hours and hours after she'd eat a chocolate. Lo behold, that child still doesn't like chocolate - not allergic to it - but it just doesn't sit well. I've known people whose infants have had issues with the mother eating orange juice as well.

> Occasionally a baby will be fussy at the breast or gassy after you eat
>   a particular food. If you notice a pattern, avoid that food for a few
>   days. To test whether that food really was the cause, reintroduce it
>   once and see if there's an effect. Mothers report that babies most
>   often object to chocolate; spices (cinnamon, garlic, curry, chili
>   pepper); citrus fruits and their juices, like oranges, lemons, limes,
>   and grapefruit; strawberries; kiwifruit; pineapple; the gassy veggies
>   (onion, cabbage, garlic, cauliflower, broccoli, cucumbers, and
>   peppers); and fruits with a laxative effect, such as cherries and
>   prunes. [Read More](http://www.babycenter.com/404_are-there-any-foods-i-should-avoid-while-breastfeeding_8906.bc)

If there is something you eat in the evening or at dinner everyday, and you are breastfeeding, consider eliminating that - or at least finding out what it is. I am not sure why you are dismissing this is a "lack of medical cause." This happens, it is a fact. The cause of it is clear too. It is not an old wives tale. And no, it is not common to medicate the child to get rid of this gas pain. It is an adjustment period for the child to very new foods. There are even [studies](http://www.journals.elsevierhealth.com/periodicals/yjada/article/S0002-8223%2896%2900013-2/abstract) on this topic.

> Relative risks (RRs) and 95% confidence intervals (CIs) for colic
>   symptoms by food items the mothers consumed ranged from 0.7 (CI=0.3 to
>   1.5) for beef to 2.0 (01=1.1 to 3.5) for cow's milk. Maternal intake of cabbage (RR=1.3, CI=1.1 to 1.5), cauliflower (RR=1.2, CI=1.0 to
>   1.4), broccoli (RR=1.3, CI=1.0 to 2.2), cow's milk (RR=2.0, CI=1.1 to 3.5), onion (RR=1.7, CI=1.1 to 2.5), and chocolate (RR=1.5, CI=1.0 to 2.2) were significantly related to colic symptoms. Maternal intake of more than one cruciferous vegetable was associated with an RR of 1.6
>   (CI=1.1 to 2.4) for infants experiencing one or more colic symptoms.

If you don't want to change your eating habits, your options revolve around switching to formula (look for ones that go down gently; formulas give gas too) or just waiting it out. The baby's body may get used to it. Clarification: Don't begin by avoiding "known gaseous foods." You'll unnecessarily be depriving yourself and your child of nutritional variety. It is better to figure out what it is that you ate that particular day that might be causing gas. Do you eat orange juice with dinner everyday? Try it in a smaller quantity or skip it for a few days. Skip garlic one day - did it make a difference? No? Okay, put it back in your diet and try skipping cauliflower next. Think of it as a game ;)

I haven't heard of four months being the magic time when gas pain goes away. Usually gas pain happens when the kid's stomach is adjusting to something new - breast milk, solids, etc. So it'll "come back" when you start your child on solids.

Comment: Interesting that there are studies on the topic.  Most of what I've consulted says that [it's not found in research](http://kellymom.com/parenting/parenting-faq/gassybaby/), so I have taken it as an old wive's tale that most of those foods (except dairy, which I read was confirmed) were problematic.  I'm a strong proponent of looking for evidence before making choices for my baby.  As for the 4 month number, that comes from my pediatrician.  It's also noted in the study you referenced and has to do with an immature digestive system.

Comment: As a note, I don't mean my comment to be combative.  It's just that no source I consulted on food and babies has mentioned any cause based on food in the mother other than milk protein allergy as being backed by research before.  I am glad to change my eating habits to help my baby, but I don't want to complicate my family's life needlessly.

Comment: I didn't take them as combative :) For the 4 month thing: my 8 month old daughter has gas now and then depending on what I feed her. She is exclusively breastfed...I ate something that gave *ME* gas and it gave it to her too. She wasn't pleased.

Comment: Also, from my understanding, there is no "one list" of food that a mother should avoid. Orange juice for some babies is perfectly fine, but not fine for a select few. Same goes with anything else. It's absurd for anyone to eliminate hundreds of nutritious foods because it MIGHT be gaseous. Its better to just figure out what that one food is that is bothering your child...and try to limit that. (Eat in smaller doses, perhaps.)

Comment: A friend's baby had horrible colic and would scream for hours. Though a process of elimination, they worked out that if the mother had pine-nuts then the child would be up all night screaming. Note the child, now a teenager, was not allergic to pine-nuts. Sometimes it does not take much to set them off.

Comment: @Swati - Re: your edit - the thing is that this is a daily problem, only at the same time.  The only things I have daily are milk, nuts, and either cereal or baked goods for breakfast.  And the milk and nuts are consumed at varying times, so it's hard to say "yes, this item from dinner caused it."

Comment: Try skipping nuts today and see what happens :) Then start the process of "which nut is driving the little one nuts!?!?" :)

Comment: And don't forget that while foodstuffs may be different, there might be ingredients in common.  Many prepared foods have soy or corn products in them, for instance.

Comment: @Swati - I'm trying skipping my big glass of milk at dinner, since that's an evening constant.  Either she's growing out of the pain on schedule, or skipping the very dairy dairy is helping.  Since "the last thing you try always works" regardless of whether it helps, I don't know if that's the issue or not until I test the milk again...but it may be it.

Comment: Does the gas pain return when you drink the milk? I'd try to be sure. I love milk, and would want to know if I am skipping it for no reason...

Comment: @Swati - nope, it actually didn't.  I love milk too, but was incentivized to skip it by a coupon for almond milk.  Since I have no more coupons (and didn't particularly like the almond milk) I went back to milk.

Comment: [Here](http://scienceofmom.com/2012/07/03/tummy-troubles-colic-and-mamas-diet/) are a bunch more studies that back up the linked one, with some analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Having now reached 16 weeks with my little one I can say that my pediatrician actually ended up being correct - time was the answer.  The gas pain began tapering off around 14 weeks and at 16 weeks has been gone for well over a week.

Unfortunately it has left in its wake sleep issues that will now have to be addressed.  Were I to do this all over again I might try modifying my diet during the earlier phases of my child's life to prevent the gas pain and subsequent sleep problems if possible.  Hence [the accepted answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5210/2146) will be a future strategy.  However I wanted to update the question with an answer that defends my pediatrician's office and provides this information for anyone else with the question in the future.

---

2 and a half years later I am going through something similar - only more acute, with my second child. My second has been declared "very gassy" by the pediatrician and has noticeable gas bubbles when you place your hand on her abdomen. She also has been diagnosed with reflux and has progressed from Zantac to Prevacid. This time I have been very proactive. When my second was a month old I did a two week trial eliminating soy and dairy from my diet completely. I spent weeks block feeding in order to eliminate my milk oversupply (a cause of gassiness in newborns). I tried probiotics, and they seemed to exacerbate the problem. I have been very diligent about burping at every feeding and before bed. Gas massages did not work in the beginning, but started to help some around 9 or 10 weeks. Unfortunately massage just ends the long episodes of night time screaming; it does not prevent them.

My second has reached 14 weeks and there is no end in sight to the gas pain. I do not know if it will begin to taper down at this point, as it did with my first. I simply wanted to update this answer to say that sometimes elimination diets, block feeding, and all the other suggestions sometimes aren't the answer, though sometimes they are.

Comment: I would think that probiotics would make the gas worse. Gas is a product of micro-organisms(such as probiotic ones) helping us digest food. More organisms = more gas. Have you tried infant gas drops (Simethicone drops)? There was a phase when we had to give our son Simethicone before/with every meal and before bed.

Comment: @CreationEdge - yes, a family member who is a pediatrician suggested Simethicone. It seems to help somewhat, but not entirely. At this point I am also considering some sort of more serious elimination diet myself, evaluating the baby to see if she needs a tongue or lip tie clipped, chiropractic manipulation, prescription drugs, and begging for a referral to a pediatric GI. Studies suggest that probiotics help with colic, which was why I tried them.

Answer (score 1):

I think Swati has made excellent valid points.  I suspect it's probably primarily gas as well.  If you don't want to approach the change in diet as an option, there are some OTC gas remedies that might help some.  You can try Mylicon gas drops (sometimes just called gas drops) or you might have some limited success with gripe water.  I wouldn't discount acid reflux either just because your child seems "happy".  My daughter had silent reflux and rarely if ever spit up, but you could hear her spit up and then she'd swallow.  Some physicians suggest his form of reflux is worse than if they actually do spit up because by swallowing they are subjecting their esophagus to the stomach acid twice.  Likewise, my niece was a happy baby and wasn't diagnosed with AR until she was almost a year old--which explained her trouble sleeping and recurring ear infections.  It may be a combination of gas pains and acid reflux that is causing the crying.  If she has a mild case of reflux, then having a gas bubble is putting more pressure on her little digestive tract and might be intensifying the AR pain.

Comment: My pediatrician suggested Mylicon (well, any Simethicone drops) and I tried them briefly, but they never seemed to help - and the pediatrician said that research backs up the fact that Simethicone doesn't make any more difference than a placebo.  As I said, I'm fine with changing my diet **if** there's evidence for it.  Swati provided some evidence, but until her excellent answer I'd never seen or heard any.

Comment: I should add that my pedi was not too optimistic that they would do anything, but told me they wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

While time may be the long term answer, and changing your diet may be the medium term answer, if you're awake at 4 am with a screaming baby who is pulling up their legs and showing every sign of gas pain, you probably want a short term answer.

We did really well with gas/colic massaging. Basically you're moving everything along for them. It can be very soothing even if gas (or not-gas) doesn't end up leaving their body, and provide immediate relief when it does. The internet abounds with articles and videos on colic massage - they basically all involve swiping moves with medium pressure from about belly button down to the pubic bone, and some involve circles as well. There is a fair amount of lifting their legs and pumping them back and forth in these internet hits that I don't recall being a thing in the days when I dealt with colic, but it probably wouldn't hurt. Here's a representative [article and video](http://www.massage-education.com/colic.html) and [some good tips](http://gentleconnections.com/massage-to-relieve-babys-colic-constipation-and-gas/) - you can probably find plenty more.

We specifically used what's called the I Love You motion - I being a straight line on the baby's left side (on your right if you're facing them) moving downward, L the same but starting with a segment 90 degrees to that, and U adding another 90 degree segment before that. I found [a good description](http://www.shoppinglifestyle.com/parenting/i-love-you-infant-massage/769/2/) online with a diagram. (If you've seen a diagram of the large intestine, you'll get it.) This can really produce output so be prepared.

Comment: Although I'm not currently mired in this issue, I wanted to mention that we did use the I Love You massage per a friend's recommendation at the time. She never seemed to release gas when I was doing it for some reason, so maybe I did it wrong? For future reference I'll come back to this diagram. Bicycling also did nothing for us. I 100% agree with wanting a short-term answer. I've told my husband that next time I will not hesitate one bit to do an elimination diet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  My baby's diapers were always green (the pediatrician was not concerned).  I tried every gas remedy all day everyday.  Then when I started pumping I noticed most of my milk consisted of fat. I looked around in the Internet for causes of green diapers and high fat milk. People suggested block feeding, as this issue is caused by an oversupply (I was taking fenugreek). I switched to formula as I could no longer tolerate the pain my baby was going through. As soon as I made the switch, no more colicky symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

My child has never had a good day after birth.1st month hiccups for 3hrs, crying from hiccups.pedi said that was colic.2nd month had serve reflux(silent so she didn't spit)screams 16 hrs day and my pediatrician said oh its just colic, until i told her she has reflux symptoms (arching back hates laying down excessive drool gas and screaming hr after feeding).3rd Month (on xantax for 30 days) reflux is manageable) The nightmare gas & sleep issues (may have my sleep disorder).5hrs of toots, screeching not crying burps 8 times, cries for sleep because painful gas keeps her up. Doc say oh they just get scared or causes little discomfort but shouldn't be painful. Here's all my tips for gas.
Following causes gas; Reflux

Difficult  Burper- make your baby release gas beforehand, i bicycle her legs during play after eating, she toots and coos no pain.Gas is only painful when it builds up.

Constipation ( Do not let you baby take 8 hr long stretches if they're poop is green.But if they just fell asleep don't wake her avoid overtiredness, i don't care if it's a inconvenience to you, it will give them painful constipation (green poop) that will last for hrs creating distrirubed sleep, and sleep issues That means.Babies don't start long stretches till they eat solids.)

Eating dairy- All babies are sensitive to a protein in cows milk that gets passed down in breast milk they can't break down some more sensitive then others.Babies don't have to be allergic to dairy to have issues.Number one cause of colic. Cow's milk is in most formulas.Giving up dairy was hard but it is a must.All breastfeed mothers should give up milk for the first 5 months. Some babies have issues with citrus but usually not.

Crying-Crying causes gas, stick a binky, rock them and colic carry ( chin in hand, belly on forearm ).
Diaper Rash- Cause pain with pooping and tooting
Change more frequently bigger diapers, baby butt lubricants and better wiping.
Breast problems / Bottle problems 
Exclusive pumping, clogged ducts, fast nipples, incorrect bottle hold, and hind milk milk foremilk in balance all causes gas infants.

Other tips
Lots of tummy time only when calm
Leg exercises only when calm
I use colic Calm instead of gas drops, she immediately calms down and stopes tooting with in 30min.
And don't be hard on yourself, they grow out of most issues by 6mth except reflux
Finally see gasologist, pediatricians are like rn, they're specialized in  growth and medicine of babies not gas, breastfeeding or sleep.

Comment: There is some good information here, but also a fair amount of questionable stuff. I'm an MD, and have never heard of a gasologist. Do you mean a gastroenterologist? Most gastroenterologists will know nothing about an infant's colic, unless they are pediatric gastroenterologists.